# Mapbox GL original addLayer should be visible

Tags: html, css, mapbox-gl-js

I have 3 options in my radio button. The code works fine on the initial load and if I keep clicking on each option other than the original option.  The problem is when I select the original checked layer (bedrooms) after I have chosen bathrooms or sq feet. The bedroom style layer is not visible, and the legend is incorrect. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    // add mapbox links and style the map
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Laughlin Housing Variance</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.37.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.37.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />


<style>

/* Proper comment for CSS */
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

/* style map - a css unique id */
#map {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
}

/* style menu - a css unique id */
#menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 480px;
        top: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* style popup - a css .class */
.mapboxgl-popup {
    max-width: 400px;
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* style legend - a css class */
.legend {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    bottom: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* style legend - a css class */
.legend h4 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
}

/* style legend - a css class */
.legend div span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>

<!-- identify the map -->
<div id='map'></div>

<!-- identify one legend for each of 3 variances -->
<div id='Bed-legend' class='legend' style='display: visible;'>
    <h4>Colors By Bedroom Variance</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #4575b4'></span>Yardi lower in beds</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #54278f'></span>Yardi equals Plan</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fcc5c0'></span>Yardi higher by 1 beds</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #f768a1'></span>Yardi higher by 2 beds</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #7a0177'></span>Yardi higher by 3+ beds</div>
</div>
<div id='Bath-legend' class='legend' style='display: none;'>
    <h4>Colors By Bathroom Variance</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #4575b4'></span>Yardi lower in baths</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #54278f'></span>Yardi equals Plan</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fcc5c0'></span>Yardi higher by 0.5 baths</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #f768a1'></span>Yardi higher by 1 bath</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #7a0177'></span>Yardi higher by 2+ baths</div>
</div>
<div id='Sqft-legend' class='legend' style='display: none;'>
    <h4>Colors By Sq Ft Variance</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #0c2c84'></span>Yardi lower: 644 - 858</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fd8d3c'></span>Yardi lower: 431 - 644</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #c6dbef'></span>Yardi lower: 50 - 431</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #fcc5c0'></span>Yardi equals Plan (+ or - 50)</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #41ab5d'></span>Yardi higher by > 50 </div>
</div>

<div id='menu'>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Laughlin Homes by Variance Type:</legend>
    <input id='Bedroom' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='Bed_Varian' checked='checked'>
    <label for='Bedroom'>bedrooms</label>
    <input id='Bathroom' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='Bath_Varia' >
    <label for='Bathroom'>bathrooms</label>
    <input id='Sq_Feet' type='radio' name='rtoggle' value='Sq_Ft_Vari' >
    <label for='Sq_Feet'>square feet</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGtheW5lMjMiLCJhIjoiN2ZuVll5MCJ9.INSHe8gm7HMfO8HZPUuAhg';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    // use any style; this is a predefined mapbox style
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v10',
    center: [-100.790, 29.352],
    zoom: 14.9
});

// add navigational control
var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
map.addControl(nav, 'top-right');

// define variables
var layerList = document.getElementById('menu');
var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');
var bedLegendEl = document.getElementById('Bed-legend');
var bathLegendEl = document.getElementById('Bath-legend');
var sqftLegendEl = document.getElementById('Sqft-legend');


// define functions
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', function switchLayer(layer) {
    var layerId = layer.target.id;
    console.log(layerId)
    // var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(layerId, 'visibility');
    map.setLayoutProperty(layerId, 'visibility', 'visible');
    // set the legend
    // If id = Bed
    if (layerId === 'Bedroom') {
       bedLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
       bathLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
       sqftLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
       map.setLayoutProperty('Bedroom', 'visibility', 'visible');
       map.setLayoutProperty('Bathroom', 'visibility', 'none');
       map.setLayoutProperty('Sq_Feet', 'visibility', 'none');
       }
     // If id = Bath
     if (layerId === 'Bathroom') {
     bedLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
     bathLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
     sqftLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
     map.setLayoutProperty('Bedroom', 'visibility', 'none');
     map.setLayoutProperty('Sq_Feet', 'visibility', 'none');
      }
    // Else id = Sq_Ft
     else {
     bedLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
     bathLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
     sqftLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
     map.setLayoutProperty('Bedroom', 'visibility', 'none');
     map.setLayoutProperty('Bathroom', 'visibility', 'none');
     }
  });


map.on('load', function () {
        // source is a TMK tileset; same source for all layers
      map.addSource('laughlincombined4326', {
          type: 'vector',
          url: 'mapbox://tkayne23.7gg2xn4y'
      });

      // add variance by bedrooms to paint units
      // can be controlled by either the filter or visibility option
      map.addLayer({
          'id': 'Bedroom',
          'type': 'fill',
          'source': 'laughlincombined4326',
          'layout': {'visibility': 'visible'},
          'source-layer': 'LaughlinForMapbox4326-8kt1ts',
          'paint': {
                'fill-color': {
                'property': 'Bed_Varian',
                'type': 'interval',
                'stops': [
                      [-5, '#4575b4'],
                      [0, '#54278f'],
                      [1, '#fcc5c0'],
                      [2, '#f768a1'],
                      [3, '#7a0177']
                    ]
                 },
                'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
                'fill-opacity': 0.9
              }
          });

        /* add variance by bathrooms to paint units
         can be controlled by either the filter or visibility option */
        map.addLayer({
          'id': 'Bathroom',
          'type': 'fill',
          'source': 'laughlincombined4326',
          'layout': {'visibility': 'none'},
          'source-layer': 'LaughlinForMapbox4326-8kt1ts',
          'paint': {
                'fill-color': {
                'property': 'Bath_Varia',
                'type': 'interval',
                'stops': [
                      [-5, '#4575b4'],
                      [0, '#54278f'],
                      [.5, '#fcc5c0'],
                      [1, '#f768a1'],
                      [2, '#7a0177']
                    ]
                 },
                'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
                'fill-opacity': 0.9
              }
          });

          // add variance by square feet to paint units
          // can be controlled by either the filter or visibility option
          map.addLayer({
          'id': 'Sq_Feet',
          'type': 'fill',
          'source': 'laughlincombined4326',
          'layout': {'visibility': 'none'},
          'source-layer': 'LaughlinForMapbox4326-8kt1ts',
          'paint': {
                'fill-color': {
                'property': 'Sq_Ft_Vari',
                'type': 'interval',
                'stops': [
                      [-858, '#0c2c84'],
                      [-654, '#fd8d3c'],
                      [-431, '#c6dbef'],
                      [-50, '#fcc5c0'],
                      [50, '#41ab5d']
                    ]
                 },
                'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
                'fill-opacity': 0.9
              }
          });

      // always create the hover effect
      map.addLayer({
          'id': 'homes-fill-hover',
          'type': 'fill',
          'source': 'laughlincombined4326',
          'source-layer': 'LaughlinForMapbox4326-8kt1ts',
          'layout': {'visibility': 'visible'},
          'paint': {
          'fill-color': '#db1e11',
          'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
          'fill-opacity': 1
          },
          'filter': ['==', 'addr_house', '']
      });

      // layer to only show that unit, thus making a hover effect.
      // it should adjust to the active layer or keep at homes-fill-hover
      // it needs to match the current layer
      // features is key

      map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
          map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
          var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['Bedroom'] });
          if (features.length) {
              map.setFilter('homes-fill-hover', ['==', 'addr_house', features[0].properties.addr_house]);
          } else {
              map.setFilter('homes-fill-hover', ['==', 'addr_house', '']);
          }
      });

      // Reset the state-fills-hover layer's filter when the mouse leaves the map
      map.on('mouseout', function() {
          map.setFilter('homes-fill-hover', ['==', 'addr_house', '']);
      });

  // When a click event occurs near a polygon, open a popup at the location of
  // the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
  map.on('click', function (e) {
      var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['Bedroom'] });
      if (!features.length) {
          return;
      }

      var feature = features[0];
      // give popup info to display
      var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
          .setLngLat(map.unproject(e.point))
          .setHTML('<div id="popup" class="popup" style="z-index: 10;"> <h4> Unit Details: </h4>' +
              '<ul class="list-group">' +
              '<li class="list-group-item"> Unit #: ' + feature.properties['Address'] + " </li>" +
              '<li class="list-group-item"> from ' + feature.properties['Yardi_info'] + " </li>" +      '<li class="list-group-item"> from ' + feature.properties['Reno_Plan'] + " </li>" +
              '<li class="list-group-item">  Renovation Unit Type: ' + feature.properties['Reno_Unit_'] + " </li>" + '</ul> </div>')
          .addTo(map);
    });

  });

  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```